# Retrieving RSSI values from all devices connected to network

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy, rssi

I'm building an application that lists the hostnames of devices connected to the network and their corresponding RSSI values. Is there any way I can collect this information for each network device?

I was able to use the WLAN API (I'm on Windows) in Python to get the RSSI values for nearby wireless LAN networks, but I want to get that information for each device connected to the network. I also tried using the scapy module in Python, but I was only able to get the hostnames, not the RSSI values.

I've done a lot of digging and haven't found a definitive answer to this. Just looking for some direction. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot actually compare RSSI between different vendors, and sometimes even between different device models of the same vendor. Each vendor has its own method for calculating that, generally trying to make their product look better than its competitors. A better measure is dBm.

Comment: Hi Ron. Thanks for the response. I would like to measure RSSI in terms of dBm, so that is fine. If I am able to get the dBm data across different devices then, do you how I could go about accessing that information?

Comment: As I explained, RSSI is calculated by each vendor in a different manner. It is possible that dBm is part of one vendor's calculation, but not for the other. RSSI is really useless unless you are using the exact same model and software version from only one vendor, but if it involves different models, software versions, or vendors, it cannot be used for comparison.

Comment: You will need to install a service on each host that can get a dBm measurement if it is available in the software of that device, and your service will report back to you. There is no standard way that all vendors use to report that. It may be in the MIB for some devices, but do not count on that.

Comment: Oh interesting. I am still learning about all of this so did not realize, but that does make sense. The reason I want this information is because I'm looking into WiFi triangulation techniques and have seen people use signal strength data as input. As such, that's what I was trying to find. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Triangulation is a different story. You should have control of the WAPs you use to perform the triangulation, and you can measure the dBm at each WAP WAP. The dBm is what the WAP hears from each host, not the dBm or RSSI on the host.

Comment: Oh I see. I think I was overcomplicating things. So just to make sure I'm understanding, a WAP stores dBm for each host connected to it (as this is what it hears from each host)? So I should be able to get all the info I need, given I control the WAPs used to perform triangulation, by measuring this data from each WAP.

Comment: If you have several WAPs, each can see the frame sent by a host, and each can detect the dBm of the signal. If you have the precise location of each WAP, based on the dBm of the host signal, you can triangulate to an approximate spot for the sending host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea based on one approach you seem to have pursued.

Code will collect the signal strength using one station as a monitoring station.

To run correctly on a Macbook you need to disconnect the interface from the network before running.

Here is sample output (x added to obscure mac addresses):

```
x4:x9:x2:ed:03:39 -78
x4:xd:x1:55:e8:de -86
x0:xa:x6:13:e6:ac -78
x8:x3:xd:63:b6:85 -87
x0:x8:xa:04:24:a2 -78
x0:x1:x6:d2:2a:65 -88
```

```py
from scapy.all import *

conf.use_pcap=True

maxrssi = {}

def callBack(pkt):
    # print(pkt.show())
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        key = None
        if not pkt.FCfield.to_DS and pkt.FCfield.from_DS:
            if pkt.addr3 is not None:
                key = pkt.addr3
        else:
            if pkt.addr2 is not None:
                key = pkt.addr2
        if key is not None:
            if key in maxrssi.keys():
                if maxrssi[key] < pkt.dBm_AntSignal:
                    maxrssi[key] = pkt.dBm_AntSignal
                    #print("NEW MAX for ", key, maxrssi[key]);
            else:
                maxrssi[key] = pkt.dBm_AntSignal
                #print("NEW MAX for ", key, maxrssi[key]);

sniff(iface='en0', monitor='True', prn=callBack, count=200)
for sta in maxrssi:
    print(sta, maxrssi[sta])
```

Suggesting, because another user recently asked [how to get RSSI using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328963/how-to-get-wifi-snr-with-python)

Comment: May I ask what the monitor='True' field does? When I run this code, I get the error AttributeError: 'NetworkInterface' object has no attribute 'ismonitor'. I have tried running similar code before, but couldn't get the program to work without throwing an error at the sniff function. Sorry, I am relatively new to scapy but am trying to learn! P.S. I am not using a macbook

Comment: Oh I think I figured out why I keep getting errors. pkt.haslayer(Dot11) seems to always return false for me, exactly the same as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73942221/dot11-not-found-in-packet-scapy-python According to that post, haslayer is broken for scapy?

Comment: Check out the [scapy trouble shooting documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#i-can-t-sniff-inject-packets-in-monitor-mode) which says [some Windows systems don't support sniffing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN)

Try using Wireshark https://www.wireshark.org/
Does wireshark work to capture 802.11?