# How to get wifi snr with python?

Tags: python, linux, wifi

I want to get the snr(signal to noise ratio) of wifi with python. Actually, I try to set network adapter(0bda:b711) into monitor mode, then I use sniff(from scapy.all import sniff) to get some packages. But, the dBm_AntNoise is None

```
type here
```

```
from scapy.all import sniff
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11
import time


def callBack(pkg):
    time.sleep(1)

    # print(pkg.addr2, pkg[Dot11].info.decode(), pkg.dBm_AntSignal, pkg.dBm_AntNoise)
    print(pkg.dBm_AntSignal, pkg.dBm_AntNoise)
    print("-----------------")


sniff(iface='wlp1s1', prn=callBack)
```

I want to get SNR of wifi with python and sniff, Is there some other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps. I was able to produce these results.

```
sudo python3 wifi.py
dBm_AntSignal -87
dBm_AntNoise= -89
dBm_AntSignal -83
dBm_AntNoise= -89
```

Using code based on what you provided.

```py
# FILE: wifi.py
from scapy.all import *

conf.use_pcap=True

def callBack(pkg):
    if pkg.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkg.type == 0 and pkg.subtype == 8:
            print("dBm_AntSignal",pkg.dBm_AntSignal)
            print("dBm_AntNoise=",pkg.dBm_AntNoise)
            
sniff(iface='en0', monitor='True', prn=callBack)
```

I suggest, investigate your OS support for dot11 packets in scapy. I used wireshark for OSX to capture the dot11 packets to see if I could and I was surprised that I had to disconnect from the wifi in order to see dot11 packets.

On the MacBook pro the dot11 packets only appear when the wifi is not selected and already negotiated a connection. Also, the value `config.use_pcap` must be `True`. Also, `monitor` is `True` to allow dot11 packets.

If you encounter an error like this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/arch/libpcap.py", line 247, in __init__
    raise OSError("Could not activate the pcap handler")
OSError: Could not activate the pcap handler
```

Try to modify the file to get more details on the error number like this:

```py
--- libpcap.py  2022-11-07 15:22:39.000000000 -0800
+++ libpcap2.py 2022-11-07 15:23:18.000000000 -0800
@@ -243,8 +243,9 @@
                 pcap_set_timeout(self.pcap, to_ms)
                 if pcap_set_rfmon(self.pcap, 1) != 0:
                     log_runtime.error("Could not set monitor mode")
-                if pcap_activate(self.pcap) != 0:
-                    raise OSError("Could not activate the pcap handler")
+                rc = pcap_activate(self.pcap)
+                if rc != 0:
+                    raise OSError("Could not activate the pcap handler rc=",rc)
             else:
                 self.pcap = pcap_open_live(self.iface,
                                            snaplen, promisc, to_ms,
```

```
After changes:
OSError: [Errno Could not activate the pcap handler rc=] -6
```

Comment: I can fetch the dBm_AntSignal, but the dBm_AntNoise is None

Comment: See updates, not sure why that value wouldn't be available

Comment: I use Ubuntu20.04. when I try to run you code, an OSError occurred as follows: OSError: Could not activate the pcap handler

Comment: Investigate the error by editing the file reporting the error, `libpcap.py` and printing the exact error number. On my linux box I saw -8 , looked in [this error code list](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/soem/html/pcap_2pcap_8h.html) and saw PCAP_ERROR_PERM_DENIED. Using sudo, then the error changed to -6 PCAP_ERROR_RFMON_NOTSUP.  So my linux adapter is wired and doesn't support wifi radio monitoring.  I will try to find a wifi adapter to test further, but you may be having the same issues.

Comment: I just plugged a wifi adapter into usb `wlan0` and now the system is reporting as the Macbook did. Maybe the lan adpater you are testing with doesn't support wifi radio monitoring? [This note in scapy documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html) says not all wifi systems support monitoring. Post the exact error number and maybe I can help more.

Comment: When I try to wash in terminal, there is some errors: sudo wash --interface wlx584120dc449c ,[X] ERROR: pcap_activate status -1 ,[X] PCAP: generic error code couldn't get pcap handle, exiting

Comment: Have a look at new edits. Trying to figure out why the adapter isn't working in your specific environment.

Comment: Now, the wash and reaver can work properly, But the the noise level is absent in radiotap information when I use wireshark to capture packets.

Comment: After changes, my error code is -1, (PCAP_ERROR   -1 ), who can help me ？

Comment: Try [asking the people who wrote libpcap](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues) they have a list of issues and can better help debug the library return codes.

Comment: Or, if the return value is `PCAP_ERROR`, try adding the value of `pcap_geterr()` to the error message.  That *particular* return code means that some error other than one of the most likely errors occurred - there are many such errors, resulting from different problems - and the `pcap_geterr()` message will give details about the particular error that caused `pcap_activate()` to fail.

Comment: The changes from https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/3796/files show the way to change Scapy to produce a useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that your particular WiFi interface supports monitor mode but not necessarily noise/SNR reporting.

For example, with a Ralink RT2870 (Alfa AWUS051NH v2), I'm seeing the same results you are - signal but not noise.

@atl - What adapter are you using that reports noise?  You do not mention in your answer which adapter/chipset you are using.  Neither does @chowhao in their question.

Comment: I use a TP-LINK network adapter. The output of "lsusb" command in terminal is: Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (After Modeswitch)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34415145)